# How to restrict a hostgroup to a specific user group? (icinga2/icingaweb2)

Tags: icinga, icinga2

I want to know how to restrict a hostgroup to a specific group of users in icinga. In case that many organizations use the monitoring system, they can only see what's inside their hostgroup/s

Answer (score 4):

In icingaweb2 go to configuration -> authorization -> roles -> create new role.

Under `monitoring/filter/objects` you can enter any filter that you would use in icingaweb2. So you can just go to Overview -> Hosts and create a filter, then copy the filter string from the url, for example:

```
/icingaweb2/monitoring/list/hosts?hostgroup_name=myhostgroups&modifyFilter=1
```

The filter string would be

```
hostgroup_name=myhostgroup
```

And you can simply enter that under `monitoring/filter/objects`.